# PHP not writing a Base64 image to html file

Tags: php, png, base64, fwrite

I have this string of data with some chords and their names:

> $html="< img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAAA4AQMAAAB31mwxAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAEVJREFUeF5jIApwgDCIEAFhEKEEwkoIEYQaLID/PxD8AMmDARpDBsaww8JAqMHUTsBkGRkow84Ok4FQQ5zJZDAG0GTCAADwOiM87WVzggAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="E" /> E

When I try to put this into a file

> file_put_contents("data2.html",$html);

I just creates an empty file.

Comment: You need to escape quotes in your assignment of the string to `$html`.  `$html="<img src=\"data ...`

Comment: 1. You never closed the `$html` variable; 2. Escape the quotes; 3. Remove the space between `<` and `img`.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `$html` variable to this:

```
$html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAAA4AQMAAAB31mwxAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAEVJREFUeF5jIApwgDCIEAFhEKEEwkoIEYQaLID/PxD8AMmDARpDBsaww8JAqMHUTsBkGRkow84Ok4FQQ5zJZDAG0GTCAADwOiM87WVzggAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="E" /> E';
```

And then do the `file_put_contents('data2.html', $html);` part.

What we did here was replace the double quotes with single quotes so you wouldn't need to escape the double quotes inside the string. I also put an end with a semicolon to your string, which was missing. Always remember to end a statement when you start it.